# Как можно обновлять данные в кэше AngularJS

Tags: веб-программирование, angularjs, web-apps

**Вопрос:** Есть ли способ обновлять кэш $cacheFactory с неким интервалом времени?

**Вот мой код:**

```
     app.service('TvServerService', function ($http, $q, Constants, $state, $stateParams, $cacheFactory, $interval, $rootScope, DeviceService, TizenSpecificEvents) {

            var Service = "TvServerService";
            var Data = $cacheFactory('TvServerData');

            var MakeRequest = function (Method, Data) {
                return $http(
                    {
                        url: Constants.TvServerUrl + Service + '/' + Method + '.json',
                        data: Data,
                        method: "POST"
                    }
                );
            };

    return {
            Data: Data,
            GetChannels: function () {
                var channels;

                if (channels = Data.get('channels')) {
                    return $q.resolve(channels);
                }

                var request = {
                  //Some code
                };

                return MakeRequest('GetChannels', request)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        switch (response.data.status) {
                            case "OK":
                              return $q.resolve(Data.put('channels', response.data));
                            case "NoAuth":
                         //Some code
                        }
                    }, function (response) {
                         //Some code
                    });
            },
            //Some code
    };
});
```

**Вот что пробовал дописать:**

```
$interval(function () {
    Data.remove('channels');
}, 18000);
```

Пробовал очищать кэш (Data.remove с интервалом n) но все ломается во view который зависим от этих данных - необходимо выйти и снова зайти в этот view чтобы все опять заработало, но по истечению времени интервала все опять ломается.
**Есть ли другие способы обновлять кэш с неким интервалом времени?**

Comment: Не очень понятно *все ломается во view который зависим от этих данных*. Пожалуйста, приведите рабочий пример кода, где, как и что ломается.